# (Applied Optimization) Value of base (x) of an isosceles triangle that maximizes area - given 2 sides.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am having issues with an applied optimization problem regarding an isosceles triangle. The problem has us attempt to find the value of the base of the triangle (x) that maximizes the area given two sides (each length 6).

I understand the basics, but am having issues with this particular problem and where to start.

I know that I need to create a function whose output I want to optimize and set everything equal to one variable. I've determined my interval based on it needing to be greater than 0 and no larger than the given hypotenuses.

Then find the derivative of the given function, and find critical points by setting the derivative to 0.

My equation was:
A = 1/2(2*sqrt{6^2-x^2})*x

Which derives to:
-2x^2+36/sqrt36-x^2

Set to 0 =
x=3sqrt2, or x=-3sqrt2 (Disregard negative since its outside the domain).

Does that make the base that maximizes the area 3sqrt2? Or is that the height? Or are they the same?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base was correct in the initial question at 3sqrt2 (4.242640687) which I realize I was only working on 1/2 of the isosceles triangle. Doubling that base gives a base length (2sqrt18 (8.485281374)) that maximizes the area of the triangle at 18.

This is verified by doing the equation in the comments (using 1/2absin(x)) and maximizing off the angle to get the same measurements.

Answer (score 0):

A more applicable formula for the area of a triangle is $A=\frac12 ab\sin\theta$ where $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of 2 sides and $\theta$ is the angle between them. Since $a$ and $b$ are given positive constants, we just need to maximize $\sin\theta$. Can you take it from here?

(In your specific case of an isosceles triangle, $a=b.$)

Comment: I don't quite understand how to do that.

Looking at it, I think I could visually maximize it to around 91.25 degrees, to give a base length of 8.58 which is similar to my above 2*3sqrt2, with a maximized area of ~18. 

But I dont know mathematically how I'd maximize the sine angle.

Comment: @confundido By one definition, $\sin\theta$ is the $y$ coordinate on the unit circle. Clearly the maximum value is $1$, achieved at $\theta=\pi/2$ (in radians) or 90 degrees. So the optimal angle is a right angle. You can find the base length using the Pythagorean Formula, and the maximum area is 18.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up working through it with your suggestion. I was confused by taking the derivative of 1/2(36)sin since it seemed too easy. Especially compared to all the work I was doing trying the more complex way above.